# How do I test a variable passed into a function?

Tags: javascript, variables

Quick question, I'm trying to pass a value to a variable and then run a function if the variable was set to something specific.  How do I do that?

I have the following example where I want to assign the value name to a form field if the variable type is set to 1.

```
function test(name,type) {
  if (type=1) {
    document.myform.name.value = name;
  }
}
```

and a link in the body of the html:

```
<a href="javascript:test('myname','1');">FILL IN MY NAME</a>
```

I also tried the following with no luck:

```
function test(name,type) {
  var checktype = type;
  if (checktype = 1) {
    document.myform.name.value = name;
  }
}
```

I'm pretty sure something like this is possible, just not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: thanks to everyone for the responses.  I knew it had to be something simple.  I also discovered on my own that if I try to set the value of the variable to something other than a number, say type == go, I need to place the value in quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function test(name,type) {
  var checktype = type;
  if (checktype == 1) {
    document.myform.name.value = name;
  }
}
```

You were missing `==`

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `==`, not `=`.  Using a single symbol will assign the value of 1 to the variable `checktype`, rather than testing for equality:

```
function test(name,type) {
  if (type == 1) {
    document.myform.name.value = name;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Yanksy yes, unless the value of type determines what you do next... :-)

Answer (score 2):

To avoid this type errors try to do this..

```
function test(name,type) {
  if (1 == type) {
    document.myform.name.value = name;
  }
}
```

In this case, if you type by mistake, 1=type, then you get an error and you locate it right way.

Comment: Very old trick, comming from the C days, how ever there is a book called Writing Solid Code, that have a lot like that. Personally I used it all the time, when I write in C/C++ - (in C# it no needed, they not let you make this mistake)

Answer (score 2):

If variable didn't pass to function argument, the argument address will be Null. Therefore you need to check the addresses with if statement inside your function. ie:

```
bool flag(int & value)
{
  if (&value == NULL) {
      return false;
  }
  else {
      return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript uses `==` for equality checks.

Answer (score 1):

```
function test(name,type) {
  if (type === "1") {
    document.myform.name.value = name;
  }
}
```

No need to use an additional variable inside the function for storing the value. Also use `===' instead of`==` if you know the type of the variable.

See **[Strict equal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)**

> Returns true if the operands are
>   strictly equal (see above) with no
>   type conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) instead of an [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators):

```
function test(name, type) {
  if (type == 1) {
    document.myform.name.value = name;
  }
}
```

If you’re using an assignment operator, the whole expression evaluates to the assigned value. That means `type = 1` evaluates to `1` that is equal *true* and the branching condition is always fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

```
function test(name,type) {
  if (type==1) {
    document.myform.name.value = name;
  }
}
```